# Prepared statement & mysqli_query on same page

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using mysqli prepared statements

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


$sql="SELECT * from users where email=? and password=?";
$result=$db->prepare($sql);
$result->bind_param('ss',$email,$password);
$result->execute();
```

As the post values are coming from user i follow this method but for eg.. I want to fetch something from database like all users

```
SELECT * from users where active=1
```

1. Should i use prepared statements here as well or simple $db->query(//code); will be fine?
2. Should i not mix simple mysqli query & prepared statements both in the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to use prepared statements whenever possible. What if your application will grow, and you will have to replace the hard-coded variables with user input?

Actually it is even better to use an ORM for this, as it let's you reuse your prepared queries whenever you need them. And even if you don't prapare them, then ORM's will encourage you to write methods like this:

```
getActiveUsers()
```

instead of writing the query each time.

Read about [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles and the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) rule for more information.

Comment: If i use an ORM do i have to take care of sql injection or Orm will do it for me?

Comment: Most ORM's take care of that for you. Ofcourse you can bypass the security build in them, but you have to try hard to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

- Should i use prepared statements here as well or simple $db->query(//code); will be fine?

If the query is static (no dynamic variable) like the one you wrote,
you are fine using simple `mysqli::query`

- Should i not mix simple mysqli query & prepared statements both in the same page?

I assume by "in the same page" you meant in a single .php file; Then there is absolutely no problem with doing that. Remember PHP parser will append all php scripts (When you do include/require ...) together and then parse them.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you mix the two is really a matter of preference. In this case, I'd say it doesn't really make all that much difference.

There is a performance difference between prepared statements vs. just plain queries. Your first query would be slower as a query (assuming you run the input through `mysqli_real_escape_string`, this has to talk to the db server). However, since the second one takes no input, making it a prepared statement would break execution into preparation and execution and incur some overhead. When it's a query you only execute once which takes no input from outside of your script, `query` is faster, marginally (I doubt your speed needs are such that it really makes a difference).

I do wonder why you're getting all of the active users, rather than filtering out to get the one you want, but there's not really enough info to say that's not what you should do. If you end up just looping through these results and grabbing the few that interest you, it would be better to put this criteria in the `WHERE` clause.